# Commits not showing up on github Contributions,although they are being shown in the repo.Any Idea why?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I am new to github and I have been playing around with git to learn its functionalities. The problem is when I do git push after git commit ,the commits do show up when I go to my github profile and click on my repo but they fail to show on my contributions graph.[image]

Above is the image of the three commits I made. However they don't how up on the contributions graph.My username as shown above is harsh244 and my repo too is shown.It has been forked from someone else.

Comment: When going to the contributers listing at https://github.com/harsh244/One-Class-Kernel-ELM/graphs/contributors I see you as contributor. Maybe you were looking at the wrong repo, e.g. the original vs. your forked one?

Comment: Still not showing up on my contributions graph in my home page

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [Why are my contributions not showing up on my profile?](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/) :

> Commits will appear on your contributions graph if they meet all of
>   the following conditions:
>
> - The email address used for the commits is associated with your GitHub
>     account.
> - The commits were made in a standalone repository, not a fork.
> - The commits were made:
>
>   - In the repository's default branch (usually
>       master)
>   - In the gh-pages branch (for repositories with Project Pages
>       sites)

In your case the 2nd condition is not respected since you repo is a fork

Comment: There's 2 commits by yudongcao on Aug 6: https://github.com/k-local-quadratization/review/commits/master. But they do not show up as contributions: https://github.com/k-local-quadratization/review/graphs/contributors . They were originally made in a branch (not a fork) that was pull requested and the PR was accepted. Why are they not showing up?